# What's the most efficient way to plot 300-400 glyphs in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

When coding up a Bokeh Server applications that produces 300-400 glyphs, I find that most of the time is spent on looping through the 300-400 ColumnDataSources to set them up for plotting.

```
for key in keys: #There are 400+ keys coding for 400+ ColumnDataSources
    p.circle('x', 'y', source=source_dict[key])
```

Setting up 1 glyph (even if empty) takes only a fraction of a second (0.1 seconds). But since I am trying to plot 400 glyphs, this actually ends up taking about 42-45 seconds. This is a bit much for when the bokeh server starts up. Because of that I am wondering: How can I speed up setting up 400 glyphs? Or is there a more efficient way of plotting these things. Whatever I am using needs to preserve the hover functionality.

Comment: Would it be possible to plot it as a single glyph only? Perhaps, by using a slightly tailored source?

Comment: My concern is that the hovertool may not work with Multi-line...I remember seeing that note from the corner of my eye. I will try to plot everything as a Muliline glyph. Let's see what happens...

Comment: Yeah, I confirmed it here: [link]http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.HoverTool[/link]. Hover Tool currently (in V12.4) does not work with multi-select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.12.4`, the `HoverTool` *does* work with `MultiLine`, so the correct answer is **"don't do that"**. Bokeh is optimized to have fewer glyphs with more data each, rather than lots and lots of glyphs with less data each. A few dozen glyphs on a plot? That's fine. Four hundred glyphs on a plot? That is probably never going to be reasonable because of the way the overhead scales differently.

See the updated answer for [multi_line hover in bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304753/multi-line-hover-in-bokeh/42707872#42707872) to see how to add a hover tool to multi-line glyphs.

Comment: Ah, the documentation needs to be updated I see. I assumed the docs were up-to-date! Let me see if I can update that part of the documentation in the coming days.

Comment: That would be very appreciated. In the mean time can you point me at where specifically it is out of date (or make an issue that does)? Much of the documentation is automated so that's easier to keep up to date, but the narrative docs take much more effort (basically have to have help from users)

Comment: As I missed the note above about http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.HoverTool[/link] yes an update to that would definitely be appreciated!

Comment: I will get to it either today or tomorrow and will post here again when it's done (and on github of course).

Comment: By the way, I tried the multi-line glyph: Plotting initial data points -> no problem. But I seem to encounter difficulties updating the datasource. When I do so, all the points disappear and don't come back. Do you have any idea what that is? I will try to post this question to the wider audience later today as a separate question.

Comment: Not offhand, would have to see code. Definitely worth a separate issue.

Comment: I figured it out: There are lots of "wrong ways" to update the column data source...I am not sure but those wrong ways lead to nothing being drawn. The way I found works: Build up lists of lists, then update the ColumnDataSource columns that way. Apparently, the number of items in the outer list should also not change or the drawing breaks. So if I have up to 400 separate lines to draw, I create 400 lists within the list, and either blank out the individual list items if need be instead of varying the number of lists within the outer list.

Comment: Well, the cardinal rule is this: all CDS columns in a given CDS must always be the same length. So of you need to make an update that changes the length of the columns, that's fine. But you have to do it by updating all of `.data` in one shot, so that there is never any time when the columns are different lengths.