# How to use Bokeh hover tool in for loop with checkbox widget

Tags: python-3.x, hover, widget, bokeh

**Python 3.6**

**Bokeh 12.15**

I have tried to implement the bokeh example [line_on_off.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/line_on_off.py), but in a for loop with a hover tool and data of varying length.  What happens though is that when a line is turned off it turns off the tool tip of any line created after it.  For example if I turn off line 1, line 2,3,4 tool tips are disabled, or if I turn off line 3 line 4's tool tip is disabled.

Can I use a hover tool and checkbox widget in a for loop like this?  I have seen [this multiline example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304753/multi-line-hover-in-bokeh), but my data is of varying length and I do not want to resample because I would like to see if there is bad or missing data.

**Code**

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

def create_plot(df_list):
    p = figure(x_axis_type = 'datetime')
    glyph_dict = {}
    labels = []
    active = []
    items = []
    names = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    callback_string = '{}.visible = {} in checkbox.active;'
    code_string = ''
    i = 0
    sources = []
    for df in df_list:
        legend = df.columns[0]
        series = df.iloc[:,0]
        labels.append(legend)
        x = series.index
        y = series.values
        source =ColumnDataSource(data = {'x':x,'y':y, 'date': [str(x) for x in x]})
        sources.append(source)
        line = p.line('x', 'y', source = sources[i])
        items.append((legend, [line]))
        name = names[i]
        line.name = name
        code_string += callback_string.format(name, str(i))
        glyph_dict.update({name:line})
        active.append(i)
        i+=1
    hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('date', '@date'),('y', '@y')])
    p.add_tools(hover)
    checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=labels, active=active, width=200)
    glyph_dict.update({'checkbox':checkbox})
    checkbox.callback = CustomJS.from_coffeescript(args=glyph_dict, code=code_string)
    return checkbox, p
```

**Minimal example**

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.plotting import show


df_list = []
start = datetime(2017, 4,1)
end = datetime(2017,5,1)
for i in range(1,5):
    date = pd.date_range(start, end, freq = '1w')
    shape = len(date)
    df = pd.DataFrame(index = date, data = np.random.randn(shape,1))
    name = 'df'+ str(i)
    df.columns = [name]
    end = end + timedelta(weeks = 1)
    df_list.append(df)


c,p = create_plot(df_list)
r=row([c,p])

show(r)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a situation like this, you should probably create a new, separate hover tool for each line, by restricting the `renderers` property of each hover tool. So, in relation to your code, move the hover tool creation inside the loop, and have it set `renderers` each time:

```
line = p.line('x', 'y', source = sources[i])
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('date', '@date'),('y', '@y')]
                  renderers=[line])
p.add_tools(hover)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately the behavior persists.  The preceding line in the for loop controls whichever lines follow it.

Comment: Your code is perfectly working when running on `master`, so apparently it was a bug that was fixed sometime during the last (ongoing) release cycle. `0.12.16` should be out next week.