# Using `line` vs `multi_line` for plotting many (differently colored) lines in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a pandas dataframe `df' in tidy format, like so

```
date          population   country
Feb. 1 2000   99999        Canada
Feb. 1 2000   98765        Spain
Feb. 2 2000   99998        Canada
...
```

I would like to do a line plot using Bokeh, where each country gets its own line and color.

One way to do this seems to be to use the `legend` keyword to `line()` to give me a different line for each country:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
plot = figure(...)
plot.line(x='date', y='count', source=source, legend='country')
```

Unfortunately, it seems like there's no straighforward to select colors for each country...

And since there's a `multi_line()` plotting function, this seems like what I should be using. However, I don't know a simple way to do this. Something like the following can work:

```
plot.multi_line(xs=[df['date'], df['date']], 
                ys=[df[df['country']=='Canada'], 
                    df[df['country']=='Canada']], 
                colors=['red', 'blue'])
```

This doesn't seem very elegant either, especially since I actually have many more conutries than the two in my toy example above.

What's the proper way to do this with bokeh?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bokeh Multi-line with hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120838/bokeh-multi-line-with-hover) & [multi_line hover in bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304753/multi-line-hover-in-bokeh)

Answer (score 1):

Short and elegant:

```
from bokeh.palettes import Category10

groups = df.groupby('country')
p = figure(x_axis_type = "datetime")
p.multi_line(xs = [df.date for i, df in groups],
             ys = [df.population for i, df in groups],
             line_color = Category10[10][0: len(groups)],)
```

More elegant:

```
from bokeh.palettes import Category10

groups = df.groupby('country')

data = {'date': [], 'population': [], 'legend': []}
for i, df in groups:
    data['date'].append(df.date.tolist())
    data['population'].append(df.population.tolist())
    data['legend'].append(i)
data['color'] = Category10[10][0: len(groups)]

p = figure(x_axis_type = "datetime")
p.multi_line(xs = 'date',
             ys = 'population',
             line_color = 'color',
             legend = 'legend',
             source = data, )
```